# Is it possible to open an application in an application like an iframe

Tags: android, kiosk-mode

I am a beginner in Android development. I am developing a kiosk for an android 6. I can not unfortunately use the LOCKTASK MODE because it is a specific hardware with users unclear.

I finally found an open source kiosk that I want to adapt. Indeed, the kiosk can control the outputs of the user, especially avoid going into the settings.
But when I launch another application, we exit the kiosk mode and the user can touch the parameters.
Hence my question, is it possible to open an application in a "launcher" application like an iframe in html?

Comment: No, sorry, Android does not offer any APIs for that.